# A drop-down box with a title - which will not be included among the options

Tags: html, css

Do you know a good implementation of a drop-down box with a title? which will not be included in the options of the drop-down box.

I am trying to place a selection box in the upper right corner of the screen which will display the user's name; when the user clicks on the name I would like to show him several options like "Sign-Out" and "Set-Up" . I do not want to display the user's name as an option only as a title.

I checked HTML5 select tag, although it does not have the ability to display a title.

It seems that this functionality exists in lots of sites these days, and I wonder if anyone heard on a good way to implement it? or an existing implementation.

Regards,
Luk

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sites I have seen this on are not using HTML form elements, but are using a floating div that is shown/hidden on the click event.  This would be my preferred choice, are you required to use a SELECT tag?

Comment: Not really, any solution will be good. That's why I mentioned a drop-down box. Thanks.